# C Union to copy memory

Tags: c, stm32

I have the following legacy code:

```
#define UINT8 unsigned char
#define UINT16 unsigned short
#define UINT32 unsigned long
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        UINT16  R1: 1;
        UINT16  S1: 1;
        UINT16  S2: 1;
        UINT16  D1: 1;
        UINT16  I1: 1;
        UINT16  S3: 1;
        UINT16  S4: 1;
        UINT16  S5: 1;
        UINT16  S6: 1;
        UINT16  P1: 1;
        UINT16  F1: 1;
        UINT16  I2: 1;
        UINT16  R2: 4;
    }bb;
    UINT16  V16;
}test_union11;

typedef struct                    /* memory index */   
{                                 /* ++++++++++++ */   
  // Write Config 01-32
  UINT16       i1;          /*    0   */         
  UINT16       i2;          /*    2   */         
  // Faults
  UINT16       o3;          /*    4   */        
  UINT16       o4;          /*    6   */       
  UINT16       o5;          /*    8   */         
  UINT16       o6;          /*   10   */         
  // Values 01-08
  UINT8        o7;          /*   12   */         
  UINT8        o8;          /*   13   */        
  UINT8        o9;          /*   14   */         
  UINT8        o10;         /*   15   */         
  UINT8        o11;         /*   16   */         
  UINT8        o12;         /*   17   */         
  UINT8        o13;         /*   18   */         
  UINT8        o14;         /*   19   */        
  // Values 09-12
  UINT16       o15;         /*   20   */         
  UINT16       o16;         /*   22   */         
  UINT16       o17;         /*   24   */        
  UINT16       o18;         /*   26   */        
  // Values 13-14
  UINT32       o19;        /*   28   */        
  UINT32       o20;        /*   32   */        

  UINT8        OctStr[8];
} test_str11;

test_str11 test_str1;
test_union11 test_union;
int test_memcpy(void) {


    test_str1.o15 = 1500;
    test_union.V16 = test_str1.i1;
    memcpy(&test_union,&test_str1,sizeof(test_union11));
}

int main(void) {
    test_memcpy();
    printf("Test Pass!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Is the idea behind the line  `test_union.V16 = test_str1.i1` that test_union.bb nested structure is filled with data from structure "test_str1"? However for some reason neither after that line nor after the memcpy that happened. Why? And what is the meaning of the numbers in the nested structure inside the union?

I tested the case when there are no such numbers with smaller union and structure and memcpy worked out, though the trick with the first element assignment didn't. However a syntax like that:

```
un = (*(test_union1*)&st);
```

also worked out for the second test, and didn't for the code presented. What is the difference between those two expressions? And does the `test_union.V16 = test_str1.i1` copy only the i1 variable or as many bytes as test_union.bb can hold?

The code should work on stm32f10x embedded platform, though it's not working even in Visual Studio on a PC at the moment. Therefore this is a pure C problem.
Thanks!

Comment: "The idea is that after the line `test_union.V16 = test_str1.i1` is called the whole structure "test_str1" is copied" – why do you think that should be the case? If a bit field is assigned, then only the value of that bit field will be affected, else it would be impossible to manipulate individual bit fields.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question:test_union11 (not test_union1)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant. Thank you for your quick answer. This is the question - how this bit field affect the whole picture. Because first there is a declaration for 32 bits allocation in memory, then bit field 1, so it should store 1 bit. I suppose everything else is just ignored and not stored. What is happening and how to get the correct result?

Comment: @lalamer If after setting only one bitfield member, it's only that particular member that is affected, then that is the correct result.

Comment: `memcpy(&test_union,&test_str1,sizeof(test_union11));` does not copy the whole structure `test_str1`. It only copies as many bytes as fit into `test_union11`. Please edit you question and add for what input you expect what output and what you actually get.

Comment: I just got the idea behind the code. So actually the idea is not to copy the structure but to copy the value of i1 and represent it in a bit wise manner. The size of the nested structure bb is 16 bits, exactly the size of v16 field. So when the expression  test_union.V16 = test_str1.i1 is called the value of v16 is distributed so that the first bit is stored in R1, second in S1, etc. I'll make the edit of the text. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not assigned anything to `test_str.i1`. If you do, I think your program will work. The idea of this union is to provide an easy way to get at the 16 bits in the unsigned int V16. However, this is platform dependant code, because an int may not be 16 bits (it is usually 32 bits).

The size of a union will be the size of its largest member. However, I am not sure what the alignment rules are for size mis-matches.

Finally, I think the best way to get at bits is by using the bit-wise operators &, | etc.

Comment: Assume that int is 32 bits. I'm using only 32 or 64 bits platforms. The alignment is not important, because it's not working neither on big or little endian. And the idea is not to use bit-wise operators, which is not very efficient and elegant when there are big structures like those.

Comment: test_str11 is not a union, it is a struct. So the value you are assigning to test_union.V16 is not defined. So how do you know whether or not the memcpy is working?

Comment: Right. Where did I say that test_str11 is a union? This should have been a typo. Well the value of test_union.V16 should hold the value of test_str11.i1 at least after the assignment. After the memcpy I expect to have some data from test_str11 in test_union. At the moment I have only zeros.

Comment: But how do you know what is in test_str1.i1? You haven't assigned anything to it. It could be zero or anything else.